# User count between a rang of numbers/ranks

Tags: php, count

I want to return x amount of members/users with a rank from 1-10, 11-24, and another from 25-35. Both users keep showing up in the NCO category. Even when one user is rank 27 and another is rank 13? I have tried messing with the symbols, changing it to just < or > or == but still run into no user showing up to both users showing up.

```
$stats['afenlisted'] = $pdo->query('SELECT count(*) from personnel WHERE rank >= "25" AND branch = "Air Force" ')->fetchColumn();

$stats['afnco'] = $pdo->query('SELECT count(*) from personnel WHERE rank >= "11" <= "24" AND branch = "Air Force" ')->fetchColumn();
```

Comment: `WHERE rank >= "11" <= "24"` this is not a proper condition...

Comment: You can use `WHERE rank BETWEEN X and Y`

Comment: So should I be making it an if statement? I feel like that wouldn't work since I am trying to get the fetch it from the database?

Comment: @aynber So would it look like this then?
```
SELECT count(*) from personnel WHERE rank BETWEEN "11" and "24"? I tried searching how to use BETWEEN and all I see is people talking about dates.

Comment: Yes, that looks correct. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between has the actual documentation, which shows letters and numbers as a comparison

Comment: `WHERE rank BETWEEN 11 AND 24`

Comment: Thank you guys so much, I would have never guessed or thought of BETWEEN. Nothing in the PHP Manual does it show that, unless I am not searching it correctly. If you want to put an answer down, I will mark it up as the best answer.

Comment: Probably because it's from SQL ;)

Comment: That makes sense now I was looking in the wrong place, it all blends together after a while and I forget where to search for information when I am working on it. Thanks, @HonkderHase, for your help also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your query is faulty

```
$stats['afnco'] = $pdo->query('SELECT count(*) from personnel WHERE rank >= "11" <= "24" AND branch = "Air Force" ')->fetchColumn();
```

As said by various people, you have different ways to accomplish a range check. I'll show 3 of them...

First:

```
SELECT .. FROM .. WHERE rank >= 11 AND rank <= 24
```

This would be the most compatible way (for SQL queries) to do the check, probably supported by the any database out there, as it uses only basic comparsion operations.

Second:

```
SELECT .. FROM .. WHERE rank BETWEEN 11 and 24
```

Though nowadays broadly supported, BETWEEN is a special keyword which might not be known by all database system.

Third:

```
SELECT .. FROM .. WHERE rank IN(11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,22,23,24)
```

While this is perfectly valid, it fits better to cases when the range has gaps. (like "11 to 24, but except 17")

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to [Aynber](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1007220/aynber), [AbraCadaver](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2844319/abracadaver), and [Honk der Hase](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2443226/honk-der-hase). For helping me understand my mistake and getting me the fix for it. So if anyone else is running into this issue, the fix is:

```
$stats['afenlisted'] = $pdo->query('SELECT count(*) from personnel WHERE rank BETWEEN 25 AND 28 AND branch = "Air Force" ')->fetchColumn();

#For your own code something like this:

$stats['Whatever you want to call it'] = $pdo->query('SELECT count(*) FROM your table name WHERE column BETWEEN x AND y AND if you have another column your trying to get from ')->fetchColumn();
```

Change the x AND y to whatever number you want, if you don't have another column you're trying to get more stuff for then just remove the AND after y (your number value)

Thanks again to those guys for helping me understand my mistakes and learning more about SQL stuff.